# CORS issue when trying to do JQuery post with json data, but not with plain text or x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, jquery, reactjs, web-services, cors

**Issue/Summary:**

Issue, i get a CORS error response when doing a jQuery post with application json data.  But I don't get that error with jQuery posts with plain/text or x-www-urlencoded-form data.

**Issue/Details:**

I have two apps running on my Ubuntu VM, a React app running on `http://localhost:3000` and a Java web service running from a Payara Server from my Netbeans 10 IDE at this url `http://cduran-virtualbox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall`.  I'm trying to test doing different jQuery Posts with different content types from the React app to the web service.

To avoid getting a CORS error message I added this to the java web server HttpServletRequest object `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");`

However I'm getting this error when doing a jQuery post with Json data:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://cduran-virtualbox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

But i have two other test methods that do jQuery Posts (one where the `content-type` is `text/plain` and the other is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` that don't have that issue.  i.e. I successfully can send a jQuery Post message to the web service and get a response back.

Here's the code of the jQuery Post with json data where **I have the CORS response issue**:

```
  var urlToPost = 'http://cduran-VirtualBox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall';

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     //crossDomain: true,
     url: urlToPost,
     async:true,
     data: JSON.stringify({ Object: 'CD', Quantity: '4' }),
     success: function(response) {
        console.log("json response: " + response);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
 });
```

Here's the jQuery post with plain text that works (ie no CORS response, i can see the web service code being reached, and i can see the response back to this React app that initiated the jQuery post):

```
var urlToPost = 'http://cduran-VirtualBox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall';

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       //dataType: "text",
       contentType: 'text/plain',
       url: urlToPost,
       data: "Hello from CommunicationForm (plain text)",
       success: function(response) {
         console.log("plain text response: " + response);
       }
   });
```

Here's my jQuery post with x-www-urlencoded-form that also works:

```
  var myObject = {
      var1: 'Hello from CommunicationForm'  
   };
   var urlToPost = 'http://cduran-VirtualBox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall';

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       //dataType: "text",
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
       url: urlToPost,
       data: myObject,
       success: function(response) {
           console.log("application/x-www-form-urlencoded response: " + response);
       }
   });
```

As further evidence, here's a screen shot of my React app, you can ignore the input text field as it does nothing.  But I have 3 input submit buttons.  As can be inferred from the button names, one does the jQuery post above with x-www-urlencoded-form content type, the other does text/plain, and the other json.

[image]

After clicking the x-www.. button this log statement ( as shown in the screenshot) is received back from the web service (indicating it works fine).

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded response: Hello back from Servlet -
>   content type received x-www-form-urlencoded

After clicking the plaintext button this log statement is shown on the screen shot which again proves that the jQuery Post works fine:

> plain text response: Hello back from Servlet - content type received
>   plain text

The last two console log messages are the CORS error response after clicking the Submit_json button.

**EDIT/UPDATE 2:**

Additional notes - Using the Post Man app I can send the HTTP Post with application/json as the content type to my Java web service app and saw the response.

I created a regular Maven Java app (not web app) and I can also send an HTTP Post with application/json as the content type to my Java web service app, and I can see the response fine in it.

When I submitted the jQuery POST with application/json from my REACT web app I saw on the network page of the developer tools on the web browser that the POST is sent as an OPTION (this happened in both Firefox and Chrome browsers).

A comment in this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22492 mentions to send simple requests, and lists out content types that don't include `application/json`.

This does make things more confusing.

**EDIT/UPDATE 1:**

Here's my back end server code.  Nothing too especial, it just checks the content-type header field and then parses the object and sends a different response back to the React app.

```
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String contentType = request.getHeader("content-type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");

        if (contentType.equals("text/plain")) {
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Plain/Text data received: " + line);
            }
            response.getWriter().print("Hello back from Servlet - content type received plain text");
        } else if (contentType.equals("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")) {
            String msgReceived = request.getParameter("var1");
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + msgReceived);            
            response.getWriter().print("Hello back from Servlet - content type received x-www-form-urlencoded");
        } else if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("json")) {
           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(request.getParameterMap());
           System.out.println("json data received: " + json.toString());
                       response.getWriter().print("Hello back from Servlet - content type received application/json");
        } else {
            response.getWriter().print("Hello back from Servlet - content type undefined");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response when you get those error messages? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Also, the console screenshot in the question shows two *XML Parsing Error: syntax error* messages being logged in the console. Why?

Comment: Even more interesting, using PostMan app, I can send a Http Post with the Content-Type set to `application/json; charset=utf-8` to my web service url, and it gets a response back fine.

Comment: I just noticed the HTTP Status code you refered to was found in the Network pane you also mentioned.                                                                          `Request URL: http://cduran-virtualbox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.1.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only values for the Content-Type header in a simple request are the following:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

Try to change the "application/json" to other content type or the browser will do a preflight request.

Refer to the CORS documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I just saw that from the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers link directives section.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found the issue, further solidyfying what Indrajit Bhaskaran answered above.

Per this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#Directives

> Note that certain headers are always allowed: Accept, Accept-Language,
>   Content-Language, **Content-Type** (but only with a MIME type of its
>   parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either
>   **application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
>   text/plain**). These are called the simple headers, and you don't need
>   to specify them explicitly.

The key take away from the above is that only those 3 Content-Types are allowed from a web site to a backend for a request.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is totally dependent on Access-Control-Allow-Origin header's value in the response and it seems that the response to the request with json content type is not receiving this header.

I think the request with JSON content type might be failing on the server side and the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is getting set only for successful requests.

Have you checked by putting a debug point on `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");` if its getting hit for your JSON content type request?

Could you please share the server code where this header is getting set ?

I am sorry that I am asking my queries in the answer section instead of comment as I can't comment at this moment.

**EDIT:**
Updated Jquery code for application/json content type POST query. Please share the raw format of request which can be seen under Network tab in case it doesn't work. As the request is not in right format, it is not hitting the implementation on server side and thats why the header is not getting set in the response.

```
var urlToPost = 'http://cduran-VirtualBox:8080/TestMavenWebApplication/firstservicecall';

  $.ajax({
     url: urlToPost,
     type: "POST",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify({ “Object”: “CD”, “Quantity”: “4” }),
     success: function(response) {
        console.log("json response: " + response);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I have updated my original post to show the back end java code.  I have to admit that even with a breakpoint in the java back end code, it never gets hit when I do the Submit_json jQuery Post.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer Per this additional information, it seems that the request being generated by the jquery code for application/json content type is incorrect. I have added an updated jQuery code for the same. After using this updated code, could you please the request in the network tab and share the raw format of the request if it doesn't work ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the CORS error response on the front end. I'm still investigating to see if there's another header field I'm missing.